# usage of ''do'' as a substitute verb

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> She can play the piano as well as he can.
>
> She can play the piano as well as he can do.

I prefer the second for having other helping verb. I have read we use ''do'' as ''substitue verb'' while there is no ''other auxiliary verbs.

Comment: Why do you need a substitute verb? The phrase expanded would be "She can play the piano as well as he can (play the piano)." The verbs are fine as is.

Comment: But *can* is an auxiliary verb, so there **is** another auxiliary verb already.

Comment: If you ***prefer*** the second version you should think long and hard about why you've come to that position. No native speakers would normally include ***do*** there, so it's important to understand why you as a non-native speaker should end up having an (incorrect) opinion on what "sounds best".

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking the full sentence is

> She can play the piano as well as he can *do* *(it)*.

Where *do it* refers to playing the piano, as in

> They both play the piano.
>   She can *do it* as well as he can *do it*.

but as @user3169 points out, the correct expansion of your example is

> She can play the piano as well as he can *(play the piano)*.

in keeping with *parallel construction*.

Answer (score 1):

> *She can play the piano as well as [he can].*

The bracketed expression is a comparative clause, and comparative clauses are obligatorily reduced in some way. Here, the complement of "can" is missing (though it is understood as "play the piano well")

The meaning is "She can play the piano x well; he can play the piano y well; x=y".